# UserMerge Error

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-extensions

I recently added the UserMerge extension to my mediawiki installation. Followed the instructions found [here](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aUser_Merge_and_Delete). 
I enabled $wgShowExceptionDetails = true; and it gave me this:

```
[f9bbe088] /wiki/index.php/Special:UserMerge Exception from line 376 of /wiki/includes/SpecialPage.php: Call to undefined method UserMerge::getPageTitle

Backtrace:


#0 /wiki/extensions/UserMerge/UserMerge_body.php(128): SpecialPage->__call(string, array)
#1 /wiki/extensions/UserMerge/UserMerge_body.php(128): UserMerge->getPageTitle()
#2 /wiki/includes/SpecialPage.php(631): UserMerge->execute(NULL)
#3 /wiki/includes/SpecialPageFactory.php(488): SpecialPage->run(NULL)
#4 /wiki/includes/Wiki.php(298): SpecialPageFactory::executePath(Title, RequestContext)
#5 /wiki/includes/Wiki.php(602): MediaWiki->performRequest()
#6 /wiki/includes/Wiki.php(467): MediaWiki->main()
#7 /wiki/index.php(49): MediaWiki->run()
#8 {main}
```

Any ideas on a fix?

Answer (score 2):

You've downloaded too new of a version of the extension.  It looks like you may have grabbed the newest version of the code from the git master rather than downloading the appropriate [snapshot version of the extension](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Special%3aExtensionDistributor/UserMerge).

The version of the extension you have makes a call to `$this->getPageTitle()` in UserMerge_body.php.  The `getPageTitle` function does not even exist (in [SpecialPage.php](https://github.com/wikimedia/mediawiki-core/blob/master/includes/specialpage/SpecialPage.php)) until Mediawiki version 1.23 (which is not yet released).