# Media wiki merge and delete a user using MergeUser extension

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-extensions

Hi i am trying to install the MergeUser plugin in media wiki. My account is in both sysop and bureaucrat. I have enabled  `$wgGroupPermissions['bureaucrat']['usermerge'] = true;`

When i try to access /Special:UserMerge i get the following error

```
[70aadcac] /index.php/Special:UserMerge Exception from line 376 of         /var/www/plivowiki/includes/SpecialPage.php: Call to undefined method UserMerge::getPageTitle
Backtrace:
#0 /var/www/plivowiki/extensions/UserMerge/UserMerge_body.php(128): SpecialPage->__call(string, array)
#1 /var/www/plivowiki/extensions/UserMerge/UserMerge_body.php(128): UserMerge->getPageTitle()
#2 /var/www/plivowiki/includes/SpecialPage.php(631): UserMerge->execute(NULL)
#3 /var/www/plivowiki/includes/SpecialPageFactory.php(488): SpecialPage->run(NULL)
#4 /var/www/plivowiki/includes/Wiki.php(298): SpecialPageFactory::executePath(Title, RequestContext)
#5 /var/www/plivowiki/includes/Wiki.php(602): MediaWiki->performRequest()
#6 /var/www/plivowiki/includes/Wiki.php(467): MediaWiki->main()
#7 /var/www/plivowiki/index.php(49): MediaWiki->run()
#8 {main}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [UserMerge Error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20976472/usermerge-error)

Answer (score 1):

You need to either upgrade MediaWiki, or downgrade the MergeUser extension. The function `SpecialPage::getPageTitle` was [introduced recently](https://git.wikimedia.org/commitdiff/mediawiki%2Fextensions%2FUserMerge.git/d5a37fcbe8f18bf38506ecc7aeaa62a7a404c613) (it was called `SpecialPage::getTitle` before).

If you can't upgrade MediaWiki to the latest version, a possible patch would be to replace `getPageTitle` with `getTitle` in `/extensions/UserMerge/UserMerge_body.php`, but of there could still be other incompatibilities.

Also, please give the versions of the relevant software and extensions when asking this type of questions, that will make it much easier to give good answers.

**Edit:** I see now that this has been answered before: [UserMerge Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20976472/usermerge-error)